# Mostrar datos de una tabla en PostgreSQL en un DataGridView en Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, vba, select, datagridview

Quiero mostrar datos de una tabla en una BD de PostgreSQL en un DataGridView utilizando una clase, el problema es que cuando realizo la consulta me muestra el siguiente error:
42P01: no existe la relación «ventas»

Pero la tabla existe, anteriormente a eso ya establesi la conexión a la BD, esta escrito igual así que se que no tiene nada que ver con mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Luego pensé que no necesito enviar información, por ende no tengo que usar un proceso, si no una función, pero me pasa lo mismo, y cuando encierro todo en un try cath directamente no me devuelve nada.
Este es el código que tengo:

-Show.vb La clase

```vb
Public Function Select_Table()
Try
        Dim query As String
        query = "Select * From Ventas"
        Dim conector = New Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand(query, conn)
        Dim datos = New Npgsql.NpgsqlDataAdapter(conector)
        Dim tabla = New DataTable()
        datos.Fill(tabla)
Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try

Return datos
End Function
```

Y este es el código de mi formulario, se ejecuta al cargar:
-frmAdministrar.vb el formulario.

```vb
Dim Con As New Conex
Con.Conectar()

Dim Show As New Show
'dtgvTest es el DataGridView.
dtgvTest.DataSource = Con.Select_Table()
```

En resumidas cuentas, los datos se seleccionan de la tabla y se rellenan mediante datos en la variable tabla de la clase, eso es lo que retorno, pero no se si al declarar esto dentro del try catch realmente no se guarda, si elimino el try catch me muestra el error mencionado anteriormente, por favor ayúdenme.

Comment: O sí, por si se preguntan que es la variable conn que uso es una variable que hace la misma conexión que con, lo hice por si acaso pero no cambio nada

Comment: En la función no devuelves la tabla...

Comment: Si, ese error también lo tenia, pero fue porque me puse a tocar cosas para intentar arreglarlo XD, antes lo tenia bien, solo cambiar el nombre de la base de datos

Answer (score 1):

Con deshonra hacia mi persona como futuro programado compartiré mi solución...

*redoble de tambores*

Me conecte a otra base de datos. Sí, no tengo que usar el try catch y listo, tenia casi todo bien, mi error era que la conexión a mi base de datos era otra, lógicamente me daría error porque llamo una tabla que no existe en dicha db.

Aquí dejare mi conexión y mi consulta por si a alguien en un futuro les interesa.

Esto dentro de la clase Conexion.vb

```vb
Public Class Conexion
    Public Con As New Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection 'variable para la conexión.
    Public Sub Conectar()
        Try
            Con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; uid=postgres; password=password; database=bodega"
'se crea la conexión y se abre, importante el nombre de la base de datos.
            Con.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Function ObtenerDatos() 'funcion para obtener los datos.
        Dim Query_Select As String = "Select * From Ventas" 'La consulta
        Dim conector As New Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand(Query_Select, Con)
        Dim datos As New Npgsql.NpgsqlDataAdapter(conector) 'aqui se almacenan los datos que llama conector.
        Dim tabla As New DataTable() 'se crear un nuevo objeto que será datatable.
        datos.Fill(tabla) 'el objeto tabla sera llenado con los datos de la variable datos.

        Return tabla 'retorna la tabla
    End Function
End Function
```

El código del formulario frmAdministrar.vb

```vb
Public Class frmAdministrar
    Private Sub Eliminar_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim Con As New Conexion

        Con.Conectar()
        dtgvTest.DataSource = Con.ObtenerDatos()
        dtgvTest.DataMember = ""
    End Sub
End Class
```

Eso fue todo, mi error fue el nombre de la bd, moraleja, revisen bien su código antes de entrar a medidas desesperadas, créanme que use una infinidad de códigos distintos XD.